# Match lengths of multiple Numpy arrays of unequal length

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm doing some data processing on data that comes in sets of 3 thousands of values long. Sometimes the arrays are of slightly different lengths, and I am trying to find a way to find the minimal length array and match the other two to that.

```
# Some randomly generated sequences
a = array([7, 1, 7, 8, 0, 0, 1, 2, 8, 7, 2, 3])
b = array([0, 1, 1, 8, 3, 4, 1, 5])
c = array([8, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 7, 3, 8, 8])

# What I'd like accomplished
a = array([7, 1, 7, 8, 0, 0, 1, 2])
b = array([0, 1, 1, 8, 3, 4, 1, 5])
c = array([8, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 7])
```

This problem seems well covered for 2 arrays of different lengths but my searches didn't bring up anything for matching the lengths of multiple arrays. Looking at some of the Numpy methods like `resize` and `array_split` didn't seem to have the functionality I was looking for. Before I dive into writing some type of ugly recursive function using the directions I found matching 2 arrays, does anyone have any suggestions about how this can be accomplished conveniently?

Comment: Since they are separate arrays (not 'rows' of a 2d) you will need to iterate twice, once to find the desired length (min) and once to generate new arrays of desired shape.  No fast compiled numpy functions to do that!

Comment: We get the data as individual files which I translated to arrays but your comment makes me think maybe I should pad them to match the max and then drop rows by index with Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we can do return the `min` length

```
mlen = min(map(len, [a, b, c]))
8
```

Then

```
newl=[x[: mlen ] for x in [a,b,c]]
```